# Apache Redirect to Jboss SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, jboss, redirection

I'm trying to have an SSL Connection to an Apache server on port 443 which I want to use to proxy connections to a JBoss server on a different port.

The SSL certificates sit on the Jboss server not on the Apache server.  Is it possible to redirect HTTPS traffic from Apache to the Jboss Server and have the JBoss server do the SSL handshake?

The Apache server must be able to redirect HTTPS traffic for two different URLS.  One for a secure site.  The other for access to web services.  By the way I'm using it mutual authentication, if that makes any difference.

What does the Apache config file need to contain? or are there any good example of this out there?

Thanks

Comment: Would ProxyPass work for this situation?

Comment: No, ProxyPass wouldn't, since this happens during the processing of the HTTP request. The SSL/TLS hanshake and connection has to be established before any HTTP traffic is sent. It's not clear why you need two different URLs to be redirected to two different places: do you mean that what you call your secure site is running on one server and your web service running on another?

Answer (score 1):

The system that negotiates the SSL connection is going to be responsible for performing the keypair handshake.

If your clients are accessing the Apache server, it would serve the SSL certificate.  The SSL certificate on JBoss would only be used by the Apache server, as it is the client in that case.

If you want the JBoss server to handle the SSL negotiation on the front-end, consider using NAT (or a PAT) to translate the ports.